# Joomla image hide in article

Tags: php, joomla, components

I'm using a Joomla component named Category Block. For example in a category i chose not to show my text and it look good. But i wanna be able to choose an image to be show only in category, not in article itself.

Link to category: http://ivatours.ro/index.php/senior-voyage
Link to article: http://ivatours.ro/index.php/senior-voyage/senior-voyage-cipru?cbprofile=1

Can i even do this? The Category Block component doesn't have an option to add an intro image or something like that...

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to include Images in Category description and then in the Joomla Administrator Panel, you would have to click on options to change "Yes" on Category Description. In that way, on your webpage, Category description will be visible.

Comment: But what if i wanna add a custom image to each article shown in my category?

Comment: This actually doesn't fix my problem since i'm using a custom module to show the article in this category. I'm asking if there's a way to hide an image in article...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Insert an image into article at very begining and after that add READ MORE. Thanks for tryin to help me!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You can use Category description to put custom html (image), then show that desc in module if it is possible without even placing image into article.